# Select Query issue for print 1st 2 decimal value if after '.' decimal value is only '0' - SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, if-statement

I'm trying to print

**Condition 1:** 1st two digit from my decimal value IF decimal column after '.' is 0.

```
EX:If Column value is 123.00000 = 123.00
```

**Condition 2:** I need to print same decimal column value IF there is some value after '.'

```
EX: If Column value is 123.00200 = 123.00200
    If Column value is 123.10000 = 123.10000
```

I have tried following query. But not getting expected output

```
SELECT
  CASE
  WHEN PARSENAME(dbo.tblS.DecColumn,1) > 1 THEN dbo.tblS.DecColumn
  ELSE cast(round(dbo.tblS.DecColumn,2) as numeric(36,2)) 
  END AS 'ColumnValue'
From
dbo.tblS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets suppose this data:

```
create table t ( n float);
insert into t values
( 1.00100),
( 1.0 );
```

query will be:

```
select
   case cast( n as int ) 
      when n then str(cast( n as int )) + '.00'
      else cast( n as varchar)
   end
from t;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7f617/7/0)

```
| SOURCE |        TARGET |
--------------------------
|  1.001 |         1.001 |
|      1 |          1.00 |
```

Comment: Gr8 job.. This is what I expected :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
SELECT
      CASE
      WHEN (dbo.tblS.DecColumn-Cast(dbo.tblS.DecColumn as int))>0 THEN dbo.tblS.DecColumn
      ELSE cast(dbo.tblS.DecColumn as Decimal(36,2)
      END AS 'ColumnValue'
    From
    dbo.tblS
```